# How to extract data from a csv file and create a line chart from it in D3.js

Tags: csv, d3.js

I have been trying to extract data from a csv file and plot a line chart from that data. My code snippet is as follows:

```
d3.csv("data_01.csv", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.attendee = +d.attendee; });

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.attendee; }));

var line = d3.svg.line()
             .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
             .y(function(d) { return y(d.attendee); });

svg.append("path")
       .datum(data)
       .attr("class", "line")
       .attr("d", line);

}) ;
```

The data_01.csv file has the following data:

```
date, attendee
12-Feb-12,80
27-Feb-12,56
02-Mar-12,42
14-Mar-12,63
30-Mar-12,64
07-Apr-12,72
18-Apr-12,65
02-May-12,80
19-May-12,76
28-May-12,66
03-Jun-12,64
18-Jun-12,53
29-Jun-12,59
```

I am not able to understand why this problem is occurring. Is it because of the location where the csv file has to be stored. Please help me in this regard.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the error? First step is to make sure the file is loaded. Add this above data.forEach: `if (error) return console.log(error)`. Is anything logged?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this problem and found that it has to do something with **Cross-origin resource sharing**. Chrome doesn't support it, but the firefox does support it. 
The solution which I am aware with is:

1. Use Mozilla firefox or
2. Deploy your app on a server and then try to access it. You can use node for it.